# Multiple Combinations with Try-Catch Blocks - Java

Tags: java, performance, parsing, try-catch

What I am doing is taking String timestamps and parsing them using the `SimpleDateFormat` class for use in a calendar. However there are multiple formats these timestamps could be in, for this example time *(10:30am vs 10am)*.

There are start and end times on this calendar I'm creating, so not only will I have to handle ParseExceptions for if the start time isn't formatted our typical `hh:mmaa`, but I've got to worry about the combination of the two. Here's what would work but I feel is utterly inefficient.

```
// Combination #1 -----------------------------------------------------
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy hh:mmaa zzz");
DateFormat endTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy hh:mmaa  zzz");
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    date.setTime(format.parse(rawStartDate));
    endTime.setTime(endTimeFormat.parse(rawEndDate)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    try {
        // Combination #2 ----------------------------------------
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy hhaa zzz");
        endTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy hhaa  zzz");
        date.setTime(format.parse(rawStartDate));
        endTime.setTime(endTimeFormat.parse(rawEndDate)));
    } catch (ParseException ee) {
        //onto another iteration until our combination runs out THEN report the exception
        // start being hh:mmaa
        // end being hhaa -- etc etc
    }
}
```

Sure as this code is odd, probably not the correct use of the `Calendar`; Regardless, I'm wanting to know if there's a better way of going about this.

Obviously I need to only change the `format` and the `endTimeFormat` variables, but I cannot leave out the seemingly redundant `date.setTime` otherwise we wouldn't know if it worked.

Comment: Are both dates the same format? Eg if rawStartDate is formate A and rawEndDate is format B, then endTime would never get set. Also, that isn't really what a finally is for. I would suggest splitting it into the two formats, formatA and formatB. The do each date in its own try/catch block. That way you know it would get set.

Comment: @matt the first format has minutes, the second doesn't.

Comment: @matt ty for the finally heads-up. Handed the code to a colleague too and said the same thing on first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a variable for the two SimpleDateFormats.  This way it can be created just once. Note: if you make it a field, you need to lock it if you use in multiple thread, or you can use the JSR-310 library added to Java 8 which doesn't need a lock.

Rather than trial and error you could look for the `:` e.g. `format.contains(":")` which would determine which format it has to match.  This would allow you to have one common try-catch block.

Comment: Its definitely a Sunday where I'm at xD Thanks. Although, would a solution to this trial-and-error be applicable anywhere else before I close this?

Comment: @echospot trial and error works better when there is no simple rule to tell the difference.  Sometimes it is easier to get the parser to work out whether the format applies.  However sometimes you have to tell it e.g. `01/02/03` could be `1st of Feb 2003 or 1903` or `2001 Feb 3rd` or `Jan the 2nd, 2003`  Trail and error won't tell you that because wny of these would parse ok.

Comment: These date-time stamps coming in the same format except for the way time is displayed. So first glance trial-and-error seemed easiest at first glance. Thanks!